# Google Maps initial location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello guys I've got a simple question to ask, when I open my map I have set the lat and long to open some coords, then I place one marker with a infoBubble opening when the map is loaded, but after that the map opens in the maker position.  I dont want that .. is it possible force the start location to open my map in the start position instead of the marker position?
thanks

```
function init() {

    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(-8.799445,-63.922042);

    map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
                               zoom: 17,
                               center: mapCenter,
                               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
          });

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-8.802732,-63.921939);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map,
                                          position: myLatLng,
                                          draggable: true,
                                          icon: icon
              });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the API when a InfoWindow will be opened tries to pan the map so that the infoWindow is fully visible.

Set the `disableAutoPan`-property of the infoWindow to `true` to avoid this.